# remove duplicates from sorted char array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, duplicates

I am to get input from the user and remove everything except the capital letters. However I do not want duplicate capital letters. Thus far the only issue I am having is removing the duplicates.

Here is the code to both sort the letters and place only the ones I want into a new array.

```
        placer=0;
  for (a = 0 ; a < ( strlen(regular) - 1 ); a++)
  {
    for (placer = 0 ; placer < strlen(regular) - a - 1; placer++)
    {
      if (regular[placer] > regular[placer+1]) 
      {
        swap              = regular[placer];
        regular[placer]   = regular[placer+1];
        regular[placer+1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }
printf("regular: %s\n", regular);     // this prints exactly as it is supposed to
    placer=0;
    for (a=0; a<strlen(regular); a++){
       if (regular[a] != regular[a+1]){
        alpha[placer] == regular[a];
        placer++;
       }
    }
printf("alpha: %s\n", alpha);        // this does not
```

As it stands the array alpha will for unknown reasons not take any characters whatsoever. Every time I try to print it, it just prints garbage.

And just to clarify:

```
char regular[81+1]="\0", alpha[26];
```

That is the declaration of the 2 arrays.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "alpha[placer] == regular[a];" should be "alpha[placer] = regular[a];" and you need to terminate alpha with '\0';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistaken "==" for "=" in line alpha[placer] = regular[a];.

So this should be

```
alpha[placer] = regular[a];
```

Comment: .....wow and here I was hoping it was actually a bigger issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: don't forget to do what @CharlieBurns suggest above, or you may get your wish.

Comment: @ryyker Good point, the string is not null terminated, unless you have pre-filled it beforehand: 'memset(alpha, 0, sizeof(alpha))' - assuming char has size of 1.